# Service in separate global or private process. What are the differences?

Tags: android, process, android-service

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc

What are the differences?

> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

I've checked and I can bind to Service no matter it is private or global, no matter if I do it within the same app or second one. (different UIDs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by private process, but normally the service runs in the default process of you application or a dedicated one (set by android:process for the service component in your manifest). Clients that have a different user Id can bind to or start your service if the service has explicitly set android:exported=true or if the service component has intent filters and not set exported to false.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported

Permissions set on the service tag can further restrict who can start and bind to your service.

Comment: You can make Service private by putting colon ':' before process name. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc

Comment: It is the process that is private in that case, not necessarily the service. Global processes allow components from different applications to share a process. The restriction if you are allowed to bind to a service or not doesn't depend on how the service is deployed.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Does it mean that making process global enables it to be shared with another apps? (I suppose they will be able to run threads in this process)

Comment: Yes. By default, all components that share the same process share one VM and one main thread. Components (even if they originate from different applications) can spawn threads within this shared process. You usually share a process to limit the system impact.

Comment: Ok, another question pops out then. I have a main process, in which main thread is a GUI one. I make another global process with Service running in it. Then I have another application, and want it to share process with the Service. How? (I know that there is a android:sharedUserId, but which process will be taken?)

Comment: Not a typical deployment strategy, but if both of your applications share the same user ID and are signed with the same certificate, setting android:process in the Application tag on the second application to the global process name should be enough to run the second application in the service process, but again, I don't know why you want to do this.

Comment: I think I found answer for my last question. `android:process` for Activity or Service of this antoher application has to be the same as the `android:process` name of the Service from the first application. Just tell me if I'm correct and thank you for your help!

Comment: "but again, I don't know why you want to do this" - I don't want to do this, I just wanted to know if and how it can be possible. :-) Curiosity. Thanks again!